# Have the leaders of UN Security Council permanent member states ever been tried for war crimes?

Tags: war-crime, international-courts, unsc

US leader Joe Biden has been declaring that Russian leader Vladimir Putin should face trial as a war criminal. However, both countries have permanent seats on the UN Security Council, which seems to make such a trial unlikely.

Has it ever happened that any such leader has been tried for war crimes while their country holds an effective hegemony?

Broadening the question, have there been international trials of war crimes committed by *any* citizen of a permanent Security Council member?

Comment: War crime tribunals for leaders seems pretty rare.

Comment: The Nuremberg and  Tokyo trials are the only examples that come to my mind and of course, those only occurred in the wake of military defeat.

Comment: Obviously no when it comes to leaders. US troops were tried for war crimes by their own courts, sometimes. It's not clear if that's what you're asking though. *International* trials are not common. Generally they are organized when there's some assumption justice wouldn't be served otherwise.

Comment: There was a tribunal in Hague for [Yugoslavian wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Criminal_Tribunal_for_the_former_Yugoslavia), as well.

Comment: @Burt_Harris WWII crimes predate the UN security council...

Answer (score 15):

The question seems to assume that a security council resolution is necessary to try somebody for war crimes. This is incorrect.

The ICC is at liberty to investigate crimes within its jurisdiction, which is described in [article 12 of the Rome Statute](https://www.icc-cpi.int/resource-library/documents/rs-eng.pdf) as follows:

> 1. A State which becomes a Party to this Statute thereby accepts the jurisdiction of the Court with respect to
>    the crimes referred to in article 5.
> 2. In the case of article 13, paragraph (a) or (c), the Court may exercise its jurisdiction if one or more of the following States are Parties to this Statute or have accepted the jurisdiction of the Court in accordance with
>    paragraph 3:
>    (a) The State on the territory of which the conduct in question occurred or, if the crime was committed
>    on board a vessel or aircraft, the State of registration of that vessel or aircraft;
>    (b) The State of which the person accused of the crime is a national.
> 3. If the acceptance of a State which is not a Party to this Statute is required under paragraph 2, that State
>    may, by declaration lodged with the Registrar, accept the exercise of jurisdiction by the Court with respect
>    to the crime in question.

Since Ukraine has [accepted](https://www.lawfareblog.com/icc-investigates-situation-ukraine-jurisdiction-and-potential-implications) the jurisdiction of the ICC for all war crimes that occurred in its territory, this condition is met, and the ICC has, in fact, [opened an investigation](https://www.icc-cpi.int/Pages/item.aspx?name=2022-prosecutor-statement-referrals-ukraine).

As for [precedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slobodan_Milo%C5%A1evi%C4%87):

> During the NATO bombing of Yugoslavia in 1999, Slobodan Milošević was charged by the International Criminal Tribunal for the former Yugoslavia (ICTY) with war crimes in connection with the Bosnian War, the Croatian War of Independence, and the Kosovo War. He became the first sitting head of state to be charged with war crimes.

Of course, arresting a head of state met with practical difficulties. However, after he fell from power in 2000, he was apprehended by local authorities, and, after significant international pressure, extradited and stood trial. He died in 2006 before a verdict was reached.

You are correct that no head of state of a permanent security council member has ever been tried for war crimes, but that may simply be because none have ever been accused of such. Since the security council plays no role in such proceedings, and apprehending the suspect practically requires cooperation of local authorities even if that nation doesn't have veto power in the security council, I don't see why the veto power would matter.

Comment: While the ICC could bring Russian soldiers and official to trial I doubt they could bring Russian leaders to trial.

Comment: Why? Milosevic was a leader, too.

Comment: It's fairly common political sniping in the US to assert various Presidents are war criminals, from Bush (either one) to Obama.  Though I have no idea if there's any life to such a view outside of the US (or even the most poisonous sectors of US politics, for that matter).

Comment: @meriton "Why? Milosevic was a leader, too." In that case there was evidence of direct connections of Milosevic with the hard line officers that carried out the massacres. In a bigger country with a long command chain and a lot of people involved it would be a lot more difficult to prove the leader direct responsibility.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy When there is a long command chain the only way to prove the involvement of the leaders is to prove that the atrocities where carried out in a systematic manner and repeated over time. So there could be more elements to accuse Bush Jr due to the years long occupation of Iraq than Putin for a war that has been going on for few months.

Comment: @meriton BTW I forgot to add that to bring a leader to trial evidence is not enough. International willingness to enforce an indictment is as much important. You can see the case of Omar al Bashir, Sudan and other African countries refused to enforce the requests coming from the Hague and he never stood trial there. For example I would never imagine China apprehending Putinduring a state visit and send him to the Hague.

Comment: @FluidCode: [The last I could find](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-54548629.amp) about Omar Al Bashir, he was standing trial in Sudan for charges of corruption, with the new Sudanese government seemingly willing to have him stand trial for war crimes once they are done with him, and in the process of negotiating the modalities of a such a trial with the ICC. If that's acccurate, his situation doesn't seem that different from Milosevic, just a bit earlier in the timeline.

Comment: @meriton No. Al Bashir was removed from power because the riots in Sudan were getting out of control. Until then the nobody in Africa wanted to enforce ICC ruling. The moment Al Bashir was removed from power is also the moment the willingness to enforce ICC indictment changed, but only as a side effect of protests for other reasons. From this case you can see that the willingness I was referring to matters.

Comment: Definitely, but it was the same for Milosevic, who was only extradited after he fell from power, and even then it took a lot of international pressure to get the new government to hand him over. Is the need for cooperating local authorities not sufficiently clear in my answer? I fully agree that this is the main obstacle for prosecution, but as both examples show, a regime change can enable the prosecution of a former head of state for war crimes committed while he held office. Put differently, diplomatic immunity expires once they are no longer head of state.

Comment: "none have ever been accused of such." <- Heads of UN security council members are accused of war crimes almost daily. ... but - not in the ICC.

Answer (score 8):

With regard to the title question of whether a leader of one of the UNSC permanent members has ever been tried for war crimes, the answer is no. The broader question of whether a citizen of these states has ever been tried for war crimes in an international court, however, has at least one example.

Ante Gotovina, who served in the Croatian War of Independence [was tried](https://www.icty.org/case/gotovina/) by the International Criminal Tribunal for the former Yugoslavia (ICTY) for war crimes allegedly committed during [Operation Storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Storm). Gotovina had previously served in the French Foreign Legion, and gained French citizenship in 1979. He was convicted in 2011 and sentenced to 24 years imprisonment, however this decision was reversed on appeal in 2012, and he was acquitted.

Answer (score 0):

neither Russia, Ukraine nor the US are part of the International Criminal Court, so I don't think they can be tried if they are not members.

"However, in cases where the alleged crime took place on the territory of a state not party to the Statute, the ICC may only exercise jurisdiction if such a state willingly submits to the jurisdiction of the ICC or if the case is referred to the prosecutor by the United Nations Security Council under Article 13(b) of the Statute." Source: https://www.jurist.org/commentary/2021/05/utkarsh-dubey-icc-jurisdiction-over-nonparty-states/

so basically unless the UN votes to condemn a person or military or group and refers them to the ICC, the ICC's jurisdiction does not apply there. Knowing that any such action would be vetoed by UN members with veto power, it is unlikely that such thing can happen realistically

Comment: I don't think that matters otherwise countries would just leave the organization to avoid the trials. Not being a member just means that they won't willingly give the person over for trial.

Comment: As for your recent edit all the crimes are happening in Ukraine which also happens to not be a member. It isn't so much a matter of Russia being a member or not as the crimes in question are not happening in Russia.

Comment: Note that jurisdiction is determined by the location of the crime, not the nation of origin of the perpetrator. Ukraine [has given the ICC jurisdiction](https://www.lawfareblog.com/icc-investigates-situation-ukraine-jurisdiction-and-potential-implications) for all war crimes that occur in its territory.

Comment: Thanks, Zmelgar, and welcome.   The lawfare article is very complete but deals with legal theory, where I'm looking for any past examples.  P.S. you might edit your answer and put the Lawfare link in.

Comment: ICC has claimed jurisdiction anywhere in the world, but a number of countries (most notably the US) have denied it that jurisdiction on the territory of the US and US allies or in any cases involving armed forces of the US or of the US allies.  [This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/41715/under-what-law-can-the-u-s-arrest-international-criminal-court-icc-judges-ove) explores various legal theories of what would happen if ICC tried to assert its jurisdiction in the US.

Comment: @wrod: I expect that's the actual answer. Trying to impose justice from the ICC upon a current or former leader of said country without that country's permission is "you have a war" territory.

Comment: @meriton Thank you, I did not realize that even though not a member, they can still allow the ICC to implement their jurisdiction. That's a little confusing to me, so what is the benefit of being members then? I don't want to deviate from the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Slobodan Milosevic, while on trial by [International Criminal Tribunal for the former Yugoslavia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Criminal_Tribunal_for_the_former_Yugoslavia) did try to call Prime minister Tony Blaire, President Bill Clinton, US Secretary of State Madeleine Albright, and other prominent western leaders as witnesses to his trial, with the intention of demonstrating that they have committed genocide in Balkans, see, e.g., [here](http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/english/doc/2004-04/14/content_323149.htm) and [here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/2002/02/16/milosevic-seeks-to-put-us-on-trial/dde242c5-1dfd-43a5-9dae-ba0aa374fb72/):

> Former Yugoslav president Slobodan Milosevic sought to open a de facto parallel war crimes trial today, saying he would call former president Bill Clinton, former secretary of state Madeleine K. Albright and other prominent Americans to respond to his allegations that the United States carried out policies of genocide in the Balkans.

> "I shall indeed avail myself of my right to examine and cross-examine witnesses," Milosevic said during the second day of his opening statement in his trial for alleged war crimes. He then ticked off names of potential witnesses that read like a who's who of world leaders from the 1990s.

However, [the highest ranking US official that testified in the court was General Wesley Clark](https://www.nytimes.com/2003/12/16/world/clark-testifies-against-milosevic-at-hague-tribunal.html), who commanded the NATO bombing campaign against Yugoslavia and who was at the time running for the US presidency.